# Projects/programs database

Tags: ms-access

I want to create database where I will enter persons and to which project/program this person signed up.

For example:

**Person: Max Stewart**

```
- Project: Website
  -- Program: What is website?
  -- Program: How to create website?
  -- Program: What do I need to create website?
```

**Person: Roger Federer**

```
- Project: Car
  -- Program: Which car brand should I buy?

- Project: Website
  -- Program: What is website?
```

---

And if I want to check which person joined to (Project: Website and Program: What is website) I'll get list:

```
- Max Stewart
- Roger Federer
```

This list would actually be a report in ms-access..

**So far I've done this**

I have 3 tables:

```
Person (PersonID, Person details...)
Project (ProjectID, ProjectName)
Program (ProgramID,PersonID, ProgramName, StartDate, EndDate)
```

Relationships:

```
Person -> (one-to-many) -> Program
Project -> (one-to-many) -> Program
```

Problem is that everytime I want to add another person to same program (program starts with new ID like this would be new program)

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a [many to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relation.

Comment: Ye well i linked both person and project table to program but it's not ok

Comment: You will need to use a junction table to implement a many to many relation.